How to design quantum circuits to encode the ket to the phase?
Suppose we have a function $f:\{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1,2,\cdots,k\}$, and a unitary $U|x\rangle |0\rangle =|x\rangle|f(x)\rangle$ for $x\in \{0,1\}^n$. Now we want to design a quantum circuit from $|x\rangle|f(x)\rangle$ to $e^{i\theta f(x)}|x\rangle|f(x)\rangle$. Can somebady have ideas to do that?

What is $\theta$ here?

Does this answer or this one answer your question?

If I understood correctly, function $f$ maps a bits-string to finite set of integers. In other words, you map qubits to qudits?

An answer for $f:{0,1}^n \rightarrow f:{0,1}^n$ is fairly straightforward, but as pointed out by @MartinVesely, your definition maps from a 2-level to a k-level system, for which I don’t even know what it would mean to implement a “circuit”.

It looks like once you have $|x\rangle |f(x)\rangle$ after the first operation $U$, you are looking for the application of a second unitary, say $U_2$, for which all states $|f(x)\rangle$ are eigenstates, each having eigenvalue $\exp(i\theta(f(x)))$ associated to the state $|f(x)\rangle$. Is that what you are pursuing here?
